# In JMeter, I wish to download an xml file during runtime from a http url and then parse the file for reading and storing as list?

Tags: xml, jmeter, beanshell

In JMeter, At the start of an execution of test case, I wish to download an XML file from an HTTP URL and then save that file running that instance of execution and read the file and storing a list.
 So where should it be done in JMeter BeanShell? If yes what would be the exact BeanShell script would be? If this can be done in Java then where to write the code in Jmeter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code:

1. File can be downloaded using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. You can read the data from the XML file using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), the extracted values will be available as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

If you need more specific steps - share the contents of your XML file and specify which values you want to be extracted and stored

Comment: Here is sample content of XML, with one mapping node and in actual XML there could be many. In this I wish to read first by namespace and once i have mapping node of namespace I wish to read "number" i.e (from="number") and respective generated-code="8". This wll be in loop.





<mapping namespaces="abc bac.delivery abc.submit abc.internal" target-type="Call">
<default value="abc" generated-code="5"/>
<map from="2" to="asgadfg" description="ror" generated-code="8"/>
<map from="3" to="CR" description="ror" generated-code="18"/>
</mapping>